# Как увеличить память, выделенную приложению?

Tags: java, android

Есть маркеры, они добавляются в приложение. Но при этом сильно страдает память, выделенная приложению. Когда в мониторинге этот показатель доходит до 132 Мбайт, приложение зависает и падает. Можно ли увеличить этот размер до 200 Мбайт?

Comment: система вроде сама определяет сколько выдавать приложению памяти, возможно вы тестите на эмуляторе и там стоит ограничение

Comment: @SviatVolkov нет система дает ограниченное количество каждому приложению.и если приходит этот лимит программа крашется.Но есть обходы наскольок я зна ю

Comment: `android:largeHeap="true"` в манифесте у тега `application`. Но лучше сразу провести оптимизации, чтобы хватало обычного размера хипа. А то и повышенного может не хватить и тогда всё равно переписывать придётся.

Comment: Конкретно для маркеров можно использовать [кластеризацию](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering?hl=ru)

Comment: @eugeneek сама кластеризация заставляет виснуть тоже.Она не совсем пригодна

Comment: а зачем грузить столько маркеров пользователю? если даже кластеризация не помогает? нужно переосмыслить док, который вы парсите, поставить доп фильтры там (например, радиус - улица, район, город, страна)

Comment: @iFr0z Бро это корпоратвиная программа и все мои советы они игнорируют и сказали делай как мы хотим.Я их обо всеем предупредил но последнее слово за ними

Comment: @test123  сам как держишься**

Comment: возможно это вам поможет в решении вашей проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size

Answer (score 1):

Единственный способ увеличить память, выделенную приложению системой, это выставить в манифесте флаг [`android:largeHeap="true"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#largeHeap).

Используйте этот флаг только если вы уверены в том, что у вас ресурсоемкое приложение, например, вы пишете игру. В остальных случаях это делать **не рекоммендуется**, скорей всего у вас есть утечки в приложении, и вы все равно получите OutOfMemoryError и с увеличенной памятью.

Подробнее про память и как бороться с утечками есть в [гайде](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory).